# Excel VBA: Detecting empty cell to end loop

Tags: vba, excel-2007

In Excel 2007 I have imported data consisting of a column of rows. I wish to set a VBA script to read through the data from top to bottom, using a loop. The loop should continue to iterate while the cell in the sixth column is not empty.
I have tried:

```
Do While IsEmpty(Cells(i,6)) = False
    ...
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

...and also

```
Do While Cells(i, 6).Value <> ""
    ...
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

The loop does what it is supposed to but an error ensues because the program goes on reading below the block of data. (I inserted "`On Error GoTo Catch`" in the loop, then after the loop "`Catch: MsgBox Cells(i, 6).Value & "Error`" so as to confirm that an error occurs).

There is nothing in the loop that would affect `Cells(i,6)`.

There are many questions in Stack Overflow about empty cells but the answers tend to avoid the issue how to detect an empty cell to make a loop end. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're on the right sheet (replace below) the code you posted should work

```
i = 1    
Do While sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value <> ""
     i = i + 1
Loop
```

Could you post a screenshot of the column end? Your error handling may be preventing the error message too, try disabling that temporarily. Do the columns all end on a certain row? You could specify "`do while not blank AND row < end row`".

Comment: I think the problem is that the line starting "Catch:" is run even if there is no error. This is rather obvious once I see it.